# SQL error when trying to execute commandquery

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

When I run the code below I keep getting the error message: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression`. What am I doing wrong?

```
con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database1.accdb"
connOledb.ConnectionString = con

connOledb.Open()
command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Artikels VALUES('1'," + txtOmsch.Text + _
                   "','" + txtCat.Text + "','" + txtAPE.Text + _
                   "','" + txtMarge.Text + "','" + txtVPE.Text + _
                   "','" + txtEen.Text + "','" + txtLen.Text + _
                   "','" + txtBreed.Text + "','" + txtDiep.Text + _
                   txtOmsch.Text + "');")

command.Connection = connOledb
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Have to agree with Daniel.  You are creating a security issue.  You should structure your command with Parameters rather then building a SQL String.

Comment: Do you know [`Bobby Tables`](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed a single quote for the second value. try this,

```
command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Artikels VALUES('1','" + txtOmsch.Text + _
                               "','" + txtCat.Text + "','" + txtAPE.Text + _
                               "','" + txtMarge.Text + "','" + txtVPE.Text + _
                               "','" + txtEen.Text + "','" + txtLen.Text + _
                               "','" + txtBreed.Text + "','" + txtDiep.Text + _
                               txtOmsch.Text + "');")
```

your code is vulnerable with sql injection, please use parameterized query since you are using `ADO.NET`, better try this code below,

```
Dim con As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database1.accdb"  
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Artikels VALUES(@val1, @Omsch, @Cat, @Ape, @VPE, @Een, @len, @breed, @diep,@Omsch)")

Using connOledb As New OleDbConnection(con)
    Using  command As New OleDbCommand()
        With command
            .Connection = con
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1",1)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Omsch",txtOmsch.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cat",txtCat.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ape",txtAPE.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@VPE",txtVPE.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Een",txtEen.Text )
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@len",txtLen.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@breed",txtBreed.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@diep",txtDiep.Text)
        End with
        Try
            connOledb.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch(ex as OleDBException)
            Msgbox(ex.Message.Tostring())
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

or `Add`

```
.Add("@Omsch", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtOmsch.Text
```

Comment: Not a fan of .AddWithValue()... it has some potentially performance killing side effects. I'd much rather see him use the .Add() option that asks for a specific type. But +1 anyway for demonstrating parameter usage: at least the security problem is fixed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I certainly agree with you. I was just only trying to show how to add parameters on the query. I guess I'll leave that with the OP. What do you think?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answers, i'll get to trying the sql safe version of the code as soon as i can and i'll report back then :)

Answer (score 0):

The first '  around the second column is missing

```
con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database1.accdb"
connOledb.ConnectionString = con

connOledb.Open()
command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Artikels VALUES('1','" + txtOmsch.Text + _
                               "','" + txtCat.Text + "','" + txtAPE.Text + _
                               "','" + txtMarge.Text + "','" + txtVPE.Text + _
                               "','" + txtEen.Text + "','" + txtLen.Text + _
                               "','" + txtBreed.Text + "','" + txtDiep.Text + _
                               txtOmsch.Text + "');")

command.Connection = connOledb

command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```